# NSIS Unicode - How to get all entries in section of INI file

Tags: nsis

At https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Get_all_entries_in_section_of_INI_file there is an ANSI version, but I need an unicode solution.

My first try was remove the A in the api calls (GetPrivateProfileSection and lstrlen),  and increasing the memory to 8192.

```
Function GetSection
    Exch $2
    Exch
    Exch $1
    Exch
    Exch 2
    Exch $0
    Exch 2
    Push $3
    Push $4
    Push $5
    Push $6
    Push $8
    Push $9

    System::Alloc 8192
        Pop $3
        StrCpy $4 $3

        System::Call "kernel32::GetPrivateProfileSection(t, i, i, t) i(r1, r4, 8192, r0) .r5"
     
    enumok:
        System::Call 'kernel32::lstrlen(t) i(i r4) .r6'
        StrCmp $6 '0' enumex
     
        System::Call '*$4(&t8192 .r9)'
     
    Push $0
    Push $1
    Push $2
    Push $3
    Push $4
    Push $5
    Push $6
    Push $8
    Call $2
    Pop $9
    Pop $8
    Pop $6
    Pop $5
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
    StrCmp $9 'StopGetSection' enumex

        IntOp $4 $4 + $6
        IntOp $4 $4 + 1
        goto enumok

    enumex:
        System::Free $3
     
    Pop $9
    Pop $8
    Pop $6
    Pop $5
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

Despite that my application crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode characters are 2 bytes, use `System::StrAlloc` to allocate the buffer or double the number passed to `Alloc`.

The ini function deals with number of characters, not number of bytes. It overflowed the buffer because you had not allocated as much as you told it.

I edited the wiki page, you can try the new version...

Comment: I tried with System :: StrAlloc but the function is still not working properly. It seems that some more change is needed.

Comment: Intop $6 $6 * 2 before the two other intops and change the + 1 to + 2. I'm on vacation, I can't compile code to check right now